# Почему не работает код

Tags: php

```
$input = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
$output = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while (!feof($input)) {
$line = rtrim(fgets($output), "\r\n");
if (mb_strlen($line) !== 1) {
    fwrite($output, $line.PHP_EOL);
```

Код должен убирать строки с 1 символом, но выводит пустой документ

Comment: вы хоть сами поняли что тут написали ?

Comment: Это мне порекомендовали)

Comment: @madfan41k, насколько я понял, код должен удалять строки из текста, которые длинной `<= 1` символу

Comment: @Let'ssayPie каким образом у вас `!==` превратилось в `<=` ? :)

Comment: Возможно из-за того что вы получаете `fgets($output)` вместо `fgets($input)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы рассмотрел такой вариант:

```
$input = file('input.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$file = array_filter($input, function($value) {
    return strlen($value) !== 1;
});

file_put_contents('output.txt', implode("\r\n", $file));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы читаете из файла для записи, соответственно в конце и получаете пустой файл.

```
$input = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
$output = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while (!feof($input)) {
    $line = rtrim(fgets($input), "\r\n");
    if (mb_strlen($line) !== 1) {
        fwrite($output, $line.PHP_EOL);
```